# HTTPERROR 400 Removing a message label gmail api python

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using this slice of code to try to remove the label "INBOX" from a message, but i'm getting error "no label to remove or specify"

`message = service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=id, body='INBOX').execute();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your body is wrong the body is a json object probably something like this

```
msg_labels =  {'removeLabelIds': ['INBOX'], 'addLabelIds': []}

message = service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                             body=msg_labels).execute()
```

You might want to check the documented example my python is very basic [messages.modify python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#python)

Comment: I did exactly this and got "Request had insufficient authentication scopes" error. How are you guys getting around this?

Comment: @thdoan you need to authorize the user with one of the following scopes https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

Comment: DalmTo thanks, I was able to fix it by modifying scopes as you recommended but forgot to update my comment :).